# How to do that Fourier transform?

Tags: scripting, integral-transforms

I want to perform Fourier Transform of $$\frac{\exp(jkr)}{r},$$
where $k=\frac{2 \pi}{\lambda}$ and $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$. The result should be $\exp\left(jkz \sqrt{1-(\lambda u)^2 - (\lambda v)^2} \right).$

My below code returns the function itself after a long time of running

```
FourierTransform[Exp[I k Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2]]/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2], 
{x, y}, {u, v}, FourierParameters -> {0, 2 Pi}]
```

Can anyone tell me what's the problem with my code? Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is `Ik` before `Sqrt[...]`? What is `z`? Do they have numerical values before running of `FourierTransform`??

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have modified my question, I is the complex operator, k=2*pi/Lambda.

Comment: You need to use correct syntax in Mathematica for any chance of getting an answer.  so `e` is `Exp` and `i` should be `I` and `e^(...)` should be `Exp[....]`.  But after doing these changes, it does not look like it can do it. But maybe if you wait long time it can.

Comment: Going to a cylindrical coordinate system might help (there seems to be such a symmetry in the integral). If I have time later, I might give it a shot.

Comment: Yes, I think I should use a Cylindrical system. However, Mathematica doesn't response also in Cylindrical system.

Comment: Your LATEX formula $\frac{\exp(jkr)}{r}$ differs from your code `Exp[I k Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2]]/(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)`. What should we trust? In both cases the usual Fourier transform does not exist for real values of `k,x,y,z`.

Comment: 1) Why are you converting to Cartesian before doing the transform?  2) Why is there a z in your expected result?

Comment: @user64494  Sorry for the mistake, I corrected the code.

Comment: Even `FourierTransform[Exp[I  Sqrt[r1^2 + 1]]/Sqrt[r1^2 + 1], r1, s]` returns the input.

Comment: Some interesting discussion in the comments of a similar question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/141900/fourier-transform-question

Answer (score 1):

So we have

```
f[r_] = E^(-I k r)/r /. k -> (2 \[Pi])/\[Lambda]
```

[image]
Taking the Fourier transform in spherical coordinates

```
FourierTransform[f[r], r, p, FourierParameters -> {0, 2 Pi}]
```

give a nice compact but complex result:
[image]
but suppose we convert to cylindrical coordinates:

```
fcy[\[Rho]_, z_] = 
 TransformedField["Spherical" -> "Cylindrical", 
  f[r], {r, \[Theta], \[Phi]} -> {\[Rho], \[Phi]2, z}]
```

[image]
and then take the Fourier transform

```
Simplify[FourierTransform[
  fcy[\[Rho], z], {\[Rho], z}, {\[CapitalRho], \[CapitalZeta]}, 
  FourierParameters -> {0, 2 Pi}]]
```

we get
[image]
Which is less compact but is real and looks oddly similar to your expected result.

I'm still not able to get the transform of the expression in Cartesian coordinates.
Interestingly, I am also unable to get the inverse Fourier transform of your expected result.

We can transfer to Cartesian coordinates with

```
fxyz[x_, y_, z_] = 
 TransformedField["Spherical" -> "Cartesian", 
  f[r], {r, \[Theta], \[Phi]} -> {x, y, z}]
```

[image]
And try to take the transform in just X and Y leaving Z constant.

```
FourierTransform[fxyz[x, y, z], {x, y}, {u, v}, 
 FourierParameters -> {0, 2 Pi}]
```

Which is basically the code you have in your question.
This ran for about 4 hours on my PC before Mathematica gave up and returned the input.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the usual Fourier transform of $$\frac{e^{-\frac{2 i \pi  \sqrt{\rho ^2+z^2}}{\lambda }}}{\sqrt{\rho ^2+z^2}}$$ does not exist so it should result in terms of generalized functions.

Comment: If I correctly understand it, `z` is treated as a constant in the question.

Comment: @user64494 Yes, z should not be in the Fourier Transform.